# binary search segmentation fault in c++

Tags: c++, binary-search

This works fine...the size of the array is just 7.

```
// item = search item
int bin(int arr[], int item, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
  if(startIndex <= endIndex)
  {
    int middle = 1 + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;

    if(item == arr[middle]) return middle;

    if(item < arr[middle])
      return bin(arr, item, startIndex, middle-1);

    return bin(arr, item, middle + 1, endIndex);
  }
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int sample[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};

  cout<< bin(sample,5,0,6) <<endl;

  system("pause");
}
```

But after increasing the size of array and searching 19...it says `segmentation fault.`

```
int main()
{
  int sample[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22};
  
  // size of array is 22
  cout<< bin(sample,19,0,21) <<endl;

  system("pause");
}
```

Why is it like that? Do I have a semantic error?

Comment: Time to step through with a debugger.  On quick look, your calculation of `middle` seems fishy.    A binary search doesn't need to be recursive either.

Answer (score 2):

Your middle calculation is wrong:

```
int middle = 1 + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
```

should be:

```
int middle = startIndex + (endIndex - startIndex) / 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Binary(int arr[], int n, int key)
{
  int s = 0;
  int e = n - 1;

  while (s <= e) {
    int mid = (s + e) / 2;

    if (arr[mid] == key) {
      cout << "Element Found At Index No. " << mid;
    } else if (arr[mid] > key) {
      e = mid - 1;
    } else {
      s = mid + 1;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;

  int arr[n];
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cin >> arr[i];
  }

  int key;
  cout << "Enter element to be searched!";
  cin >> key;

  Binary(arr, n, key);

  return 0;
}
```